# RichFaces 3.3.3 with JSF 2.0 working example

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jsf-2

I'm very new to JSF and i'm looking for a pure configuration of JSF 2.0 with RichFaces 3.3.3.Final. The documentation  on JBoss website is for JSF 1.2. I also find this [jboss article](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/RichFaces333andJSF20) but the sample application has a lot of configurations.

If you have successfully made RichFaces and JSF 2 work, please share you config.
Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to add the latest [facelets](http://facelets.java.net/), [richfaces 3.3.3](http://www.jboss.org/richfaces/) and [jsf 2.x](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/) libraries.
this is my web.xml config i'm using for my project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Production</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DISABLE_FACELET_JSF_VIEWHANDLER</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!--Configuration for Richfaces-->
    <filter>
        <display-name>RichFaces Filter</display-name>
        <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <!--End of the configuration part for Richfaces-->

    <!--Configuration for Facelets-->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.jsp</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.RECREATE_VALUE_EXPRESSION_ON_BUILD_BEFORE_RESTORE</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.VIEW_MAPPINGS</param-name>
        <param-value>*.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!--End of the configuration part for Facelets-->


    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>


</web-app>
```

and this is what you can find on my library:
standard.jar (for JSTL)

jstl.jar (for JSTL)

jsf-facelets.jar (Facelets 1. 1. 15)

richfaces-api-3.3.3.Final.jar

richfaces-impl-jsf2-3.3. 3.Final.jar

richfaces-ui-3.3.3.Final.jar

commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar

commons-collections-3.2. 1.jar

commons-digester-2.0.jar

commons-logging-1.1.1.jar

jsf-api.jar (for JSF2)

jsf-impl.jar(for JSF2)

HTH.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this RichFaces 4 template for Tomcat 6: http://mkblog.exadel.com/2010/06/richfaces-4-alpha-2-is-now-available-project-template/ . Just replace the alpha version with M1 version.  Also, starting with RichFaces 4, there is zero configuration.

Comment: He's asking for Richfaces 3.3.3. Richfaces 4.M1 is far from being complete yet.

Comment: I guess it depends what the OP is asking for. If the goal is to try RichFaces 3.3.3, then JSF 1.2 should be used (there is really not much that JSF2 adds to it). If the use wants to try JSF2 features, then RichFaces 4 should be used (M1).

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is the problem you have? Lot of configurations? A too huge `web.xml`? Well, that's what you get for it. Either just follow the documentation carefully - it's clear enough, *or* just look for another component library which require less configuration, like [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org). Basically all you need to add is a [single resource servlet](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/primefaces_users_guide_260710.pdf).

If you want more assistance in getting RichFaces to work, you'll really need to be more clear about the **actual** problem. "Lot of configurations" isn't a *technical* problem. It's between your ears. Error/warning messages and odd symptoms are *real* problems. You should elaborate about that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figure out that him say a 'lot of configurations' because is not just what he is trying to do with his project, I have the same problem, I need run an JSF 1.2 app with Richfaces 3.3.3 on Glassfish 3; but the app is big that change the Richfaces version is not an option; we just need the app just as is running in gf3 with minimal changes.