# upgrading JBoss 4.2.3 to JSF 2.1/2.2

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, jboss, jboss-4.2.x

I have a Seam 2.1 application running on JBoss 4.2.3 GA.

I am currently experiencing JSF compatibility problems with IE9+. However, due to other compatibility issues I can't upgrade the server version.

my current configuration is:
- JBoss 4.2.3 GA (Java 6)
- Seam 2.1.0.SP1
- JSF 1.2
- Rich Faces 3.3.X

Which components needs to be upgraded and how are they migrated?

Comment: You will have to be more specific , JSF and IE9 are two different technologies. At the end of the day IE will be provided Javascript and HTML. next question do you want to upgrade the entire server to jsf2 or just the one application ?

Comment: Link for entire server (https://community.jboss.org/wiki/UpgradeJBossASToJSF2)

Comment: @KennethClark I would upgrade the entire server. However, I don't know which components from the server/application should be upgraded also (Seam/RF/Dynamic web module).

Comment: It looks like with some effort you can get Seam 2.2.1 working , but you will probably want to upgrade that to the latest version. 
below is a link for richfaces
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483851/richfaces-3-3-3-with-jsf-2-0-working-example

Comment: If you want to use JSF 2.x then RichFaces 3.3.x should be updated to RichFaces 4.3.x